# Steve Kaufman says 勉強するな to mean don't study. Why not say 勉強しない?

Tags: conjugations

So in this video: https://youtu.be/oFXqrmfi_SU

Steve Kaufmann talks about not studying the basics in English but he says するな instead of しない is this allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

勉強するな is an imperative negative, an order not to do something (in this case studying)

勉強しない is a simple negative in the sense of I/you/he don't/doesn't study, or colloquially a request to not do something (勉強しない[でください])

Comment: Am I the only one who found that video really strange, BTW? Aside from tuning out partway in because of the choice of video footage (and the part where the guy has an entire channel of essentially making the same argument over and over), it felt to me like his speech register and intonation were all over the place. But maybe that's the expected result of trying to learn purely from immersion without study, given a broad range of sources?

Comment: I find his videos a bit odd personally, he claims to speak all these languages but his Spanish seemed really basic.